# Tag synonym request: [tag:towny] ↔ [tag:minecraft-towny]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, minecraft

The two questions tagged [towny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/towny) are about the Minecraft Bukkit plugin/mod, so I propose that they be renamed as such. [towny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/towny) should be  [minecraft-towny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-towny) because they are the same thing, and newcomers may mistaken the tag for a game actually named Towny, which, to my research, does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems reasonable. Request granted. *Bangs Gavel*

Comment: That was fast. Hooray!